# How call a function by pressing enter key in password input field in Login view?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a login view. When I press login button I call `handleFooterBarButtonPress` function.
How can I manage the enter-key action to call the same function when I press enter when I am in password field?

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
        controllerName="view.login" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <Page title="WEBAPP">
        <content>

        <FlexBox
          alignItems="Center"
          justifyContent="Center">
          <items>
            <Image src="general/img/logo.png" width="{/widthL}"/>
          </items>
        </FlexBox>

        <FlexBox
          alignItems="Center"
          justifyContent="Center">
          <items>

            <l:Grid
            defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
            width="auto">
            <l:content>
              <f:Form id="loginForm"
                minWidth="1024"
                maxContainerCols="2"
                editable="true">
                <f:title>
                  <core:Title text="" />
                </f:title>
                <f:layout>
                  <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                    labelSpanL="3"
                    labelSpanM="3"
                    emptySpanL="4"
                    emptySpanM="4"
                    columnsL="1"
                    columnsM="1" /> 
                </f:layout>
                <f:formContainers>
                  <f:FormContainer>
                    <f:formElements>
                      <f:FormElement label="Username">
                        <f:fields>
                          <Input id="id_inputUsername" />
                        </f:fields>
                      </f:FormElement>
                      <f:FormElement label="Password">
                        <f:fields>
                          <Input id="id_inputPassword" type="Password" />
                        </f:fields>
                      </f:FormElement>
                    </f:formElements>
                  </f:FormContainer>
                </f:formContainers>
              </f:Form>
            </l:content>
          </l:Grid>


          </items>
        </FlexBox>


        </content>
        <footer>
        <Bar>
         <contentRight>
            <Button id="idButtonLogin" text="Login" type="Emphasized" visible="true" press="handleFooterBarButtonPress" icon="sap-icon://accept" />
         </contentRight>
        </Bar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

Comment: By the way, it's normally good practice to respond to answers for questions you've previously asked, before asking new ones. Please don't just be a consumer - participate and share.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On an `sap.m.Input` control, enter causes the `change` event to be fired. So you can set a handler on that, and that handler can fire the press event* on the `sap.m.Button` control.

View:

```
<Input id="id_inputPassword"
  type="Password"
  change="onPasswordChange" />

...

<Button id="idButtonLogin"
  text="Login"
  type="Emphasized"
  visible="true"
  press="handleFooterBarButtonPress"
  icon="sap-icon://accept" />
```

Controller:

```
onPasswordChange : function(oEvent) {
  this.getView().byId("idButtonLogin").firePress();
},

handleFooterBarButtonPress : function(oEvent) {
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
  sap.m.MessageToast.show("Login!");
}
```

[Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/geluc/1/edit?html,js,output) courtesy of JSBin.

> warning: firePress is protected, so you may want to do something different

Comment: it work, but I have the same problem I have explained below: when I press Enter key I have double execution of code!!

Comment: Hi qmacro, your code will trigger Login event handler when the input is lost focus.

Comment: Sorry qmacro. It work! ;)  But why if i use "attachBrowserEvent" the function associated fire twice?
Thankyou!

Comment: Allen, this is true, but also perhaps what is wanted in this case.

Comment: qmacro, it will result in unexpected login issue. please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just trying out Code Snippet new feature .

**Answer:**

You can attach onsapenter event of sap.m.Input.

```js
sap.ui.controller("test.controller", {

  onInit:function(){
    
     var input     = this.getView().byId("id_inputPassword");
    
    input.onsapenter=(function(oEvent) {
      this.handeLogin(input.getValue());
    }).bind(this);
    
  },
  
  handleFooterBarButtonPress : function(oEvent) {
    this.handeLogin(this.getView().byId("id_inputPassword").getValue());
  },
  
  handeLogin:function(password) {
    
    alert("Hanlde Login "+password);
  }

});

var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewContent : jQuery("#view1").html()
});
oView.placeAt("content");
```

```html
<script
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
<mvc:View
  controllerName="test.controller"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <Input id="id_inputPassword" type="Password" />
  <Button id="idButtonLogin" text="Login" type="Emphasized" visible="true" press="handleFooterBarButtonPress" icon="sap-icon://accept" />
</mvc:View>
</script>
<body class="sapUiBody" id="content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`submit` event](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.m.Input#events/submit) in your input:

```xml
<Input id="id_inputPassword" type="Password" submit=".handleFooterBarButtonPress" />
```

> This event is fired when user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#id_inputPassword').on('keydown',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $('#formLogin').submit();
    }
});
```

Since you have problems with multiple fires of the event I added the e.stopPropagation, so no more times the event will be fire.

Comment: If I attach by this
`onAfterRendering: function(){
  var thisJs= this;
  this.byId("id_inputPassword").attachBrowserEvent('keydown', function(e){  
       // check key code  
       if(e.which == 13){
        alert("ENTER");
        //thisJs.handleFooterBarButtonPress("");
       }  
  });
 },`

when I press Enter key I have double execution of code!!

Comment: looks like you are executing 2 times the onAfterRendering event, can you try putting the alert before declaring "thisJs" var?

Comment: I try. onAfterRendering function run only onece

Comment: if you use the e.stopPropagation then will only execute once.

Answer (score 0):

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputUserName").attachBrowserEvent('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
            var userName = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputUserName").getValue();
            var password = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputPassword").getValue();
            if (userName.length == 0) {
                sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputUserName').setValueState('Error');
                sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputUserName').focus();
            } else if (password.length == 0) {
                sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputPassword').setValueState('Error');
                sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputPassword').focus();
            } else if (userName.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
                    //YOUR LOGIC
            }
        }
    });


//another way by using sap's default saponenter function
sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputPassword").onsapenter = function(e) {
         var userName = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputUserName").getValue();
         var password = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputPassword").getValue();
         if (userName.length == 0) {
             sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputUserName').setValueState('Error');
             sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputUserName').focus();
         } else if (password.length == 0) {
             sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputPassword').setValueState('Error');
             sap.ui.getCore().byId('inputPassword').focus();
         } else if (userName.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
             //your logic
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find the following code to make it work.

```
$('#idButtonLogin').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Here you can call the function
    }
});
```

Comment: The action should be executed when press enter in password input, not button, and also bind is deprecated.

Comment: oh, sorry, i missed that.